# Derivative of x^(2x)

Tags: derivatives

Maybe a simple question but I can't find a good example of it on the internet.
What is the derivative of:

$x^{2x}$

What is the simplest method of determining the derivative and what kind of rules are involved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: $x^{2x} = e^{2x \ln(x)}$. Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Consider $y=x^{2x}$. Take $\log$ both side. So, we get $\log y=2x \cdot \log x$. Then apply chain rule..